# NSURLConnection Connection Change

Tags: ios, xcode, download, nsurlconnection

I use an NSURLConnection to download a file from a web server. 
If the connection changes from 3G to Wifi while downloading, the download is not getting faster - it seems it still uses the 3G connection. How can I support changing from 2G/3G/4G to Wifi when downloading something? 
Thank you!

```
 UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
            bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
                [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
                bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }];

 urlReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlPDFListPath]
 urlConn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlReq delegate:self];
 [urlConn start];
```

Comment: Is `Wi-Fi Assist` turned off?

Comment: Even the App Store app behaves this way when I'm downloading large applications.